# Display hidden list with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, display

I want to show/hide the items from a list when the input is clicked. The page needs to start with the list not being displayed, but the code only works if it starts with the list being displayed.

```js
function fAbreGuias() {
  var vGuias = document.getElementById('guias');
  if (vGuias.style.display == "block") { // if vGuias hidden, display it 
    vGuias.style.display = "none";
  } else { // if vGuias displayed, hidden it
    vGuias.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```css
ul#guias li {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav id="menu">
  <input type="image" src="_imagens/menuesboco.png" onclick="fAbreGuias()" />
  <ul id="guias">
    <li>Guia 1</li>
    <li>Guia 2</li>
    <li>Guia 3</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Can you share fiddle example for this?

Comment: The problem is that your CSS sets the display on the `<li>` elements but your JavaScript changes the display of the `<ul>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your CSS with the below one, you were targeting the wrong element.

```
ul#guias{
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help...

```js
 function fAbreGuias() {
    var vGuias = document.getElementById('guias');
        if (vGuias.style.display == "block"){ // if vGuias hidden, display it 
            vGuias.style.display = "none";
        }
        else{ // if vGuias displayed, hidden it
            vGuias.style.display = "block";
        }
    }
```

```css
ul#guias{display :none;}
ul#guias li {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav id="menu">
    <input type="image" src="_imagens/menuesboco.png" onclick="fAbreGuias()"/>
    <ul id="guias">
        <li>Guia 1</li>
        <li>Guia 2</li>
        <li>Guia 3</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Style display property is used to hide and show the content of HTML DOM by accessing the DOM element using JavaScript/jQuery. To hide an element, set the style display property to “none”. document.getElementById("element").style.display = "none"; To show an element, set the style display property to “block”

Answer (score 0):

Set your  to display: none; for your list to be hidden, the id of the parent element ul has to be display: none; so that when the input is clicked the desired function will take effect.

Answer (score 0):

To hide an element, set the style display property to “none”. `document.getElementById("element").style.display = "none";` To show an element, set the style display property to **“block”**

Answer (score 0):

To Hide a list

```
document.querySelector('#guias').style.display = 'none';
```

To Display a list

```
document.querySelector('#guias').style.display = 'block';
```

Answer (score -1):

In your css I can see you added ul to your #. it should just be #guias

Comment: No, that's incorrect. While `#guias` would also select the same unordered list, prepending the `ul` simply makes the selector more restrictive, but still valid. Say they have a script that moved the ID to a paragraph, as odd as that may be, then the CSS rule wouldn't apply.

Comment: But Id can be used just once and the Id was redefined in the script so using just the id will block the list out.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is the css. Add another style tagged ul#guias and set the display to none.